SwiftUI Create the infinite scrolling using ZStack
I have implemented the scrolling ZStack and handling the offset modifier to place the content as such, so that each element shows in linear way. Please check the below code for more information.
ZStack {
    ForEach(0..<records.count, id: \.self) { index in
        VStack {
            Image(records[index].name)
                .offset(x: viewState.width + CGFloat(index - currentIndex) * (UIScreen.width - 60) + dragOffset, y: 0)
        }
    }
}


Source Code: https://github.com/ram2386/cardScrolling
I plan to enhance the current implementation by incorporating infinite scrolling functionality. For i.e. when the user reaches the last item and continues scrolling to the right, the first item will seamlessly appear, allowing the content to loop continuously. Similarly, when the user is at the first item and scrolls to the left, the content will cycle back to the last item, creating a smooth, continuous scrolling experience. Please refer to the kind of sample GIF below for a visual representation of the intended functionality.

And I have attempted several approaches to implement this functionality, such as swapping items when the user reaches the last or first position. However, these methods did not achieve the desired seamless infinite scrolling effect.

I am aware that implementing this functionality using ScrollView
with scrollTargetBehavior and scrollTargetLayout is feasible in iOS 17. However,
since our requirement is to support devices running iOS 15 and
later, we need to explore alternative approaches that are compatible
with earlier versions of iOS.

Please let me know if anyone has any solution to accomplished it.
Thanks in advance.

If you are looking for an example carousel implementation then there is a good one in this answer
